# Auto incremental number in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I want formula for automatic increment in Column C of 10, if the item in column A is same, but again starts from 10, if the item changed.

```
A         B         C
```

1  Amit    Eating      10
2  Amit    Drinking    20  (10+10=20)
3  Amit    Sleeping    30  (10+10+10=30)
4  Sunil   studying    10
5  Sunil   Playing     20  (10+10=20)
6  Sunil   Reading     30  (10+10+10=30)
7  Ravi    Playing     10
8  Sunil   Dancing     40  (10+10+10+10=40)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following formula starting from C2 (C1 is always 10):

```
C2: =MAX(IF($A$1:C1=A2,$C$1:$C1))+10
C3: =MAX(IF($A$1:C2=A3,$C$1:$C2))+10
C4: =MAX(IF($A$1:C3=A4,$C$1:$C3))+10
...
```

Make sure you press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER after you type the first formula (so that it will be used as an array formula) - then you can just drag and drop.

Basically, each value of C is `maximum value + 10` from all previous C column values, corresponding to the current A column value.

[image]

Comment: Giving Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Manufactured         opr.  Task            
11LOC028  10 175  
11LOC028 #VALUE! 207  
11LOC028 #VALUE! 150  
11LOC037 #VALUE! K100175

Comment: Make sure you type the exact formula for C2: =MAX(IF($A$1:C1=A2,$C$1:$C1))+10 and then press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

Comment: You can see the screenshot above, you should just make sure that your test file looks exactly like that one.

Comment: My sheet is not like this.